# Bundle size increas using react icons

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-icons

I noticed that using react-icons exponentially increases the bundle size. I have seen many questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them provided a satisfactory answer.

I have around 10 components that use a total of 20 icons from react-icons, and this increases the bundle size to 5MB.

Without using react-icons (but including 10 other custom icons in SVG format), the bundle size is only 495KB.

Can you suggest a solution to reduce the bundle size while still using icons for my project?

example of usage

```
import { LuWheatOff, LuSalad } from "react-icons/lu";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re encountering is likely an issue with your bundler being unable to treeshake the `react-icons/lu` import: which is why you see such a bloated size as the entire icon library is imported as long as you import a single component from it.

It seems that you might need to do a deep import from `@react-icons/all-files` instead: refer to their readme https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/

```
import { LuSalad } from "@react-icons/all-files/lu/LuSalad";
import { LuWheatOff } from "@react-icons/all-files/lu/LuWheatOff";
```

Comment: It solve one issue with the size . but the problem most of the icons not exist in the all-files (even this specific example not including the lu folder)